# Mootools datepicker for availability

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'm trying to make an interface where the user can define the days he is available by adding rows of "from then to then". So in the end the user must be able to make a list like this:

- From 24 Feb 2010 to 3 March 2010
- From 27 March 2010 to 18 April 2010
- From 8 May 2010 to 18 July 2010
- And so forth.

I had the idea of using óne datepicker to select both the 'from' date and the 'to' date. A bit like this: http://i49.tinypic.com/23w9s9w.png. This should return "From 1 March to 29 March".

Two questions: do you think this is a proper way of doing this and is there a script available that can do this already? I tried searching the web but I find it really hard to describe what i want, since google tends to ignore words like *from* and *to*.

Greetings,

Bas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking about usability, maybe the best solution is having the user click somewhere (let say the input box, or a calendar icon), then having him choosing the start date and a second click to choose the end date, then write down the selection.

Maybe you can find a picker in the forge, but even searching well, I think you'll have to write it by yourself.

Just focus in usability, not in which is the "smartest" way to do it, couse users uses to get stuck.